# How to get response statusCode from filterRequest function Ballerina

Tags: http, logging, request, response, ballerina

I am new in Ballerina, I try to print a log that containe some request informations like path .. and statusCode which is a response information.
How can I do that safely ?

I want to make the both  logs in same log
public function filterRequest(http:Caller caller, http:Request request, http:FilterContext context) returns boolean {
log:printInfo(remoteAdress + " " + request.method + " " + request.rawPath);
return true;
}

```
public function filterResponse(http:Response response, http:FilterContext context) returns boolean {

    log:printInfo(response.statusCode.toString());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using ballerina 1.2.x distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Currently only service name and resource name can be accessed from `http:FilterContext` by default. However, any request properties such as rawPath and method can be added to the `http:FilterContext` `attributes` map. This can be retrieved in the `http:ResponseFilter`

```ballerina
public type RequestFilter object {
    *http:RequestFilter;

    public function filterRequest(http:Caller caller, http:Request request,
            http:FilterContext context) returns boolean     {

        map<any> attributesMap = context.attributes;
        attributesMap["rawPath"] = request.rawPath;
        attributesMap["method"] = request.method;

        return true ;
    }
};

public type ResponseFilter object {
    *http:ResponseFilter;
    public function filterResponse(http:Response response,
            http:FilterContext context) returns boolean     {

        log:printInfo(context.getServiceName());
        log:printInfo(context.getResourceName());

        log:printInfo(context.attributes["rawPath"].toString());
        log:printInfo(context.attributes["method"].toString());

        return true ;
    }
};
```